# SharePoint 2013 - Offer to create Wiki page that does not exist

Tags: wiki

My company has just setup a SharePoint Foundation 2013 server that we'd like to use for our intranet site. We also have an in-house written order management program that I'd like to provide an easy way to associate user generated content/help to.  Many of the Wiki packages I've looked at have a feature where if a user lands on a page that doesn't exist they have the ability to create it and then start editing that page.

For example if a user is on some screen of our app and clicks help I'd launch this context sensitive URL:

```
http://sharepoint/sites/it/Wiki/This_Part_Changes_Based_On_Where_The_User_Clicks_Help.aspx
```

With SharePoint I'd have needed to create the This_Part_Changes_Based_On_Where_The_User_Clicks_Help on some other page and requested it to be created.  Can I automate this?  I know I can create custom 404 pages, so I assume that is a start, but I don't know how to code up said page.

I'd like to solve this in SharePoint rather than using another Wiki package because I really like the ease of editing pages.  My users would probably ignore something that required using Wiki markup so a solid WYSIWYG is key for us.